# Understanding type ascription issues

Tags: types, rust, integration-testing

I am sorry, but I am so lost that I'm not sure how to frame the question. If you have a suggestion for a better title, please let me know.

I [researched](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36390114/8469664) type ascription, and found that it is the ability to annotate an expression with the type we want it to have.

I defined the following trait and function. From my limited understanding, I am specifying the type to be `u16`:

```rust
//  src/range.rs

pub struct Range {
    pub min: u16,
    pub max: u16,
    pub current: u16
}

impl Range {
    pub fn new(min: u16, max: u16, current: u16) -> Self {
        Range{ min, max, current }
    }
```

Next, I wanted to test `new()` inside my integration_tests:

```rust
//  tests/integration_tests.rs

use confine::range::Range;

#[test]
fn new_confine() {
    assert_eq!(Range{min: 1, max: 6, cursor: 1}, Range::new(min: 1, max: 6, cursor: 1));
```

Why is the compiler confused by the type when I specifically defined the struct to be u16? I tried explicitly writing `1u16` too.

I am receiving the following error:

```
error: expected type, found `1`
 --> tests/integration_test.rs:5:70
  |
5 |     assert_eq!(Confine{min: 1, max: 6, cursor: 1}, Confine::new(min: 1, max: 6, cursor: 1));
  |                                                                    - ^ expected type
  |                                                                    |
  |                                                                    tried to parse a type due to this type ascription
  |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the main difference between initializing a struct and calling a function in Rust. When initializing a struct, the fields are named (assuming the struct has named fields), but named arguments are currently unsupported for functions.

To call `Confine::new`, simply leave out the `min:`, `max:` and `cursor:`.

```rust
assert_eq!(
    Range {min: 1, max: 6, cursor: 1},
    Range::new(1, 6, 1)
);
```

---

Now to explain the error. The arguments of a function are comma-separated lists of expressions, so (e.g.) `min: 1` is parsed as an expression. This goes fine until the `:`. An expression containing `:` (in that position, at least) has to be type ascription (which is unstable, but still implemented in the grammar). That implies that the rest of `min: 1` has to be a type, so `1` is parsed as a type. This clearly goes wrong since `1` is an integer, not a type.

None of this has anything to do with the actual types of the arguments. Just having `(1, 6, 1)` as above will be enough to infer that they're `u16`.

---

By the way, this distinction between structs and functions can be exploited to give something like named parameters. Instead of taking the arguments individually, the function takes a struct as its only argument. Then when calling the function, you initialize a struct using its named fields and pass that to the function. There are more sophisticated things you can do in this direction, but that's the basics.